# How to install Twitter on Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: tablet, twitter

I've just done a factory reset on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, which is now running Android 4.1.2.

I've been to the Google play store and tried to search for Twitter app, but it doesn't show up.

I've found it in a search and followed the link, but it's showing `This app is not supported on your device`.

All other apps like Facebook, Instagram, Skype, etc, etc, show up and install fine, but not Twitter. Any ideas why?

Note : I've tried to update my android software, but this says there is an error and it can't be installed.

Answer (score 0):

**The latest version the Twitter app supports for Android 4.1+ is 6.39.0 (March 22, 2017).**

Play Store prevents app installation if it is incompatible with the device (as of January 2020, [AppBrain](https://www.appbrain.com/app/twitter/com.twitter.android) shows the minimum of Android 4.4+).

One way to install old apps is by downloading the APK and installing it. The APK is available on [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/twitter-inc/twitter/twitter-6-39-0-release/). The device also needs to be set to allow installation from unknown sources.

Note that even if it is possible to install the app, there is no guarantee that the app will work smoothly since it also depends on the current Twitter infrastructure. In that case, it is also possible for some browsers to create a shortcut on the home screen to the Twitter site.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but I don't particularly want to install the `old app`, I'm looking at getting the latest official Twitter app, as I've done with Facebook and instagram ( + several others ). How can I update to Android 4.4+?

Comment: @WSix [Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 only supports Android 4.1.2 officially](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_3_7_0-5422.php). Thus, you have to rely on custom ROM for newer Android. You can refer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152) to find custom ROM, or [this site](https://www.getdroidtips.com/custom-rom-galaxy-tab-3-7-0/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into trying to upgrade via ROM, but I'm not sure about doing it just for running Twitter. Maybe I'll just stick to the online version - or use tweetdeck in the Firefox App.